# Where Can i import the CSV file Product information in salesforce

Tags: product, data-model

I've a contact list for the force.com site's user in salesforce. when any user purchase Product(Items) by using my website. I ll get a CSV file of all purchased product by all user at the end of day.

CSV file contain purchased product information.
Now I've to import CSV file into salesforce and attached to related contact.

CSV file column: Product name, Customer Id, Weight, Dimentions, Price.

On which object I can insert the the CSV file data, on Standard `Product2` object? Or can I create my custom object?

Comment: Not exactly sure about your data-model, You should try using a standard object link Opportunity, with that you can easily manage the records. Opportunities would be linked to Accounts but you can create custom lookup fields as per your requirement.

Comment: This question seems to be quite broad.  
It sounds like you need to work on your data model (a data model specifies which objects hold what data, and also specifies how the objects are related to one another). My company stores data about what products/services our customers have ordered in the standard `Asset` object. `Product` could be involved, but that object is more meant for storing the products that you offer rather than tracking the individual units that you've sold.